# How to calculate linar velocity of planet orbit?

Tags: simulations, solar-system, software, orbital-motion

I try to simulate a solar system with planets (with random mass) placed randomly around a sun with a mass $X \times \text{solar mass}$.

The simulation is going well when I use real data (sun,earth,moon for instance), but now I'd like to simulate randomly generated system.

My problem is that I didn't succeed in calculating linear velocity of planet.

On internet, I only found formulas to calculate linear velocity when we know the angular velocity, this mean knowing the time the planet make to do a revolution , which I don't want to determine.

I want, knowing only the distance and the two mass (and direction of velocity vector), be able to calculate the linear velocity vector.

I don't really have more information to provide, if you need something, just ask for it.

Comment: The distance, the two masses, and the direction of the velocity vector simply do not determine the magnitude of the velocity. You need something more.

Comment: And what do i need ?

Comment: Either one of: the angular velocity, the angular momentum, the period (time it takes to make one revolution), orbit eccentricity, distance of shortest approach, and there are many more possible parameters.

Comment: What @Joe said, you need one more piece of information. Also, I'm not quite clear on whether you're asking for a way to get your initial conditions (which is a good question), or whether you're asking for equations to update the velocity at each timestep (in which case you may be off to a shaky start - calculating the velocity from your parameters - +1 more of course - is likely to introduce a systematic error). If I had to pick one extra parameter to assign, I think I'd go with eccentricity (given your desire to make things random, it seems the most naturally randomizable).

Comment: Also curious as to what kind of integration method you're using. This (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration) is usually my weapon of choice for a quick and dirty simulation as it's pretty good at conserving energy for ~periodic orbits. There are, of course, many other good choices, and the one you pick may affect how you want to calculate the velocity.

Comment: @Kyle I need the "initial" velocity , I already can update the velocity using nbody. If i should add a parameter I think that should be the eccentricity since it's surely something I'll be playing with too. By the way sorry for the confusion in my question , I have some difficulties to ask technical questions in english :/. Don't hesitate to suggest edition

Comment: Agree fully with @Kyle. If you want to do this with an n-body code, see also [this scicomp question](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3566/what-is-the-correct-way-of-integrating-in-astronomy-simulations). If you're not careful with your integration scheme, your planets could very well fly off at superluminal speeds after a few orbits. Also, a pretty good approximation is to neglect planet-planet interactions and treat the star as immovable, in which case an n-body code is overkill for this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need one more piece of information to determine the magnitude of the velocity.

You said that you might use the eccentricity, so in that case you can use the formula given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_eccentricity) and deduce a quadratic equation on the velocity which yields:

$$ v= \sqrt{\frac{G M}{r \sin(\alpha)} (1 \pm \epsilon)}, $$

where $G$ is the gravitational constant, $r$ is the distance between the two masses, $M$ is the bigger mass (I assumed here that one mass is much bigger than the other), $\alpha$ is the angle between the velocity vector and the radius, and $\epsilon$ is the eccentricity.

Note that since we had a quadratic equation, you still have two options for the velocity, both consistent with the given eccentricity.

Comment: This is perfect ! thanks a lot. Just to be sure , the α is always PI/2 or -PI/2 , no ?

Comment: No! $\alpha$ can be anything from 0 to $\pi / 2$. Remember this is not restricted to a circular orbit. I did assume $\alpha$ is positive, otherwise just take its absolute value.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want to have stable orbits. Then you know that the centrifugal force equals the gravitational force:

GmM/r² = mv²/r

with G = Newtons constant, r the distance and m the mass of the planet and M the mass of the central object. Since you know the distance and the mass of the central object (the mass of the planet cancels out) you can calculate v.
v² =GM/r

Comment: This is only for a perfectly circular orbit, and the OP did not pose such a restriction.

Comment: Sorry, this was not clear for me

Comment: that's one of the formulas I found but when i apply it , I got extremly high result (eg: for earth fixed vector is 29.783 and generated with your formula : 941690.7474866967)

Comment: @eephyne - note that one of the parameters I mentioned in my comment is the orbit eccentricity. When you use this formula you're restricting yourself to a circular orbit, meaning you take the eccentricity to be zero.

Comment: @Joe , I know , but since I didn't found anything , I was testing this one

Comment: @eephyne: I get $\sqrt{1.99 \times 10^{30} \times 6.673\times 10^{-11}/1.49\times 10^{11}}$ = 29847, which is the correct value.

Comment: @JohnRennie I just notice why my result was wrong. I was using 1.49e8 instead of 1.49e11 because I use all value in km but didn't change my G constant.

Comment: @eephyne - happy to see you found your mistake. I Just wanted to add that even if you do decide to have a circular orbit and you use this formula, you also need the direction of the velocity to be perpendicular to the radius, and I don't know if you have that freedom since you said in your question that the direction was already determined.

Comment: @Joe ,It's determined because I choose to make all the planet rotate the same way. By the way when you talk about eccentricity , if you know a formula, it interest  me a lot.

Comment: @eephyne - what do you mean "all the planets rotate the same way"? As for the formula for eccentricity, I gave it in the answer I just added.

Comment: @eephyne: for an elliptical orbit see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_orbit and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit_equation.

Comment: Incidentally, @user20071 I thought the downvote to your answer was harsh since your answer was both correct and helpful, if incomplete. I've upvoted to remove the downvote.